# How to get Photoshop to retain toolbox / panel positions when swapping displays?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop

I use a laptop to do my daily work. When at the office, 80% of the time I am plugged into an external monitor. The other 20% I am going mobile -- in meetings, at home, etc. Whenever I go from being plugged in to 'mobile', Photoshop will forget its toolbar positions and settings.

Is there a way to fix this? How?

Note that the laptop's screen has 1920x1080 resolution, whereas the external monitor's screen has 1900x1200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't forget them so much as they cease to be relevant when given another display's geometry. Have you tried defining two different workspaces and simply switching between them?

Comment: I will try your suggestion and post my results back.

Comment: This sort of answers my question. Photoshop still 'forgets', but by switching to the Default Workspace and then switching back to my defined one I am able to set menus and palettes back the way I want them.

Comment: Don't rely on any default and you'll probably be much happier.

Comment: I did save a custom one. By switching back to default I mean switching from my saved workspace to the default and back to the saved. It's essentially just a couple of clicks compared to having to resize / reposition everything each time. Either way good answer :)

Comment: By the way I would vote your answer up, except I only have 13 reputation points right now -- I need at least 15 :(